# Запуск функции через другую команду

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такая функция, она запускается через кнопку `submit` в форме с `id="savebaseform"`:

```
$('savebaseform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var BB = get_blob();
    saveAs(
          new BB(
              [savebasetext]
            , {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' + document.characterSet}
        )
        , (databases[nowbase][0].name) + '.txt'
    );
}, false);
```

Как мне сделать, что бы эта функция запускалась через обычную ссылку, например `<a href="#" id="save">click</a>`?

Comment: `$('savebaseform').addEventListener('submit'` замените на `$('#savebaseform').on('submit'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых ваш код по идее не должен работать, поскольку 1) форма должна быть выбрана не как *$('savebaseform')* а как **$('#savebaseform')** 2) *addEventListener* - это метод *DOM-объекта*, а то что вы написали - это *jquery* обертка над DOM-объектом. В вашем случае подойдет *document.getElementById('savebaseform').addEventListener()*

Ну а по существу, можно тело обработчика события обернуть в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее по клику на ссылку. Примерно вот так:

```
function foo(e) {
    var BB = get_blob();
    saveAs(
        new BB(
            [savebasetext]
            , {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' + document.characterSet}
        )
        , (databases[nowbase][0].name) + '.txt'
    );
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', foo);
```

И код ссылки такой:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="save">click</a>
```

Comment: а для чего `void(0)`?

Comment: @Stack это вместо `#`, чтобы по клику на ссылку она (решетка) не добавлялась к урлу и чтобы страница не скролилась в самый верх. Такая запись отменяет действие по-умолчанию.